# how to avoid objects from array going out of scope after file is closed?

Tags: c++, arrays, polymorphism

So basically what is going on is this. The code works perfectly fine to add the objects into the array. But when I close the accountFile, the entire array becomes NULL. How can I avoid this so that I can use the array for other things?

```
accounts = new Account*[numAccounts];

for (int i = 0; !accountFile.eof(); i++)
{
    if (accountFile >> tempAccountType)
    {
        if (tempAccountType == "Checking")
        {
            accountFile >> tempAccountNum >> tempBalance >> tempTransFee;
            CheckingAccount tempAccount(tempBalance, tempAccountNum, tempTransFee);
            accounts[i] = &tempAccount;
        }
        else
        {
            accountFile >> tempAccountNum >> tempBalance >> tempIntRate;
            SavingsAccount tempAccount(tempBalance, tempAccountNum, tempIntRate);
            accounts[i] = &tempAccount;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not when you close the file the issue is you are taking a refrece to a local object that is destroyed when the local goes out of socope

first I would define accounts as a vector of smart pointers

```
std::vector< shared_ptr<Account> >
```

Then create a new one every time you read the file

```
accounts.push_back( make_shared<SavingsAccount)(tempBalance, tempAccountNum, tempTransFee);
```

This will exist as long as the vector exists.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because of your object's scope. Your tempAccount object is destroyed when it is out of its scope. Try this:

```
//some stuff
if (tempAccountType == "Checking")
{
    accountFile >> tempAccountNum >> tempBalance >> tempTransFee;
    CheckingAccount *tempAccount=new CheckingAccount(tempBalance, tempAccountNum, tempTransFee);
    accounts[i]=tempAccount;
}
else
{
    accountFile >> tempAccountNum >> tempBalance >> tempIntRate;
    SavingsAccount *tempAccount=new SavingsAccount(tempBalance, tempAccountNum, tempIntRate);
    accounts[i] = tempAccount;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Account>> accounts;

while(accountFile >> tempAccountType)
{
    if(tempAccountType == "Checking")
    {
        accountFile >> tempAccountNum >> tempBalance >> tempTransFee;
        accounts.emplace_back(new CheckingAccount(tempBalance, tempAccountNum, tempTransFee));
    }
    else
    {
        accountFile >> tempAccountNum >> tempBalance >> tempIntRate;
        accounts.emplace_back(new SavingsAccount(tempBalance, tempAccountNum, tempIntRate));
    }
}
```

1) Checking !eof() is not good enough. I restructured the loop

2) Use a vector

3) Use smart pointers (in this case unique_ptr)

4) Don't store pointers to local scope objects. You must allocate

Answer (score 0):

The objects are going out of scope because they're declared in the if block. You are saving them by reference, so when they fall out of scope, the reference becomes invalid.

Try the following:

`accounts[i] = tempAccount;`

This will call the copy constructor for `CheckingAccount`, which will save a copy instead of a reference.